# What is necessary to upload to iTunes Connect for Store Kit testing?

Tags: iphone, ios, storekit

Most tutorials I've been able to find are dated and inconsistent with regard to what is actually necessary to have uploaded and approved in iTunes Connect.  Following one tutorial I uploaded incomplete binary and rejected it.  I then added an In App Purchase Item.  I uploaded an image and filled in all the registration information.

So currently,

1. App - Status -- Developer Rejected
2. In App Purchase Item -- Ready to Submit

I am able to make requests to the store kit, but I am getting 0 results.  Is it possible to get results with my current iTunes Connect statuses?

Edit: I appreciate the trouble shooting advice.  But I want to make sure that it is in fact possible to retrieve purchase items with the above statuses.

Comment: Make sure that you have accepted all the necessary tax contracts too for paid apps. It won't work without those completed first.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that you provided all the details for the app including the in app purchase details along with screen shot.
2. Next is to make sure that the app ID's are same in server and in the app.
3. When testing in-app purchase, create test account in app store and use it for testing. Make sure that the mail you are using is not existing. Also on your device, you have to use those test credentials to test the app.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible as I just managed to do it.  My problem was tax info.  Thanks to Paul Mason, your comment was the correct answer!